# Why don't our poor hands get the same Latin-rooted medical care as our feet?

Tags: terminology, medical

If we want our feet checked, we go to a *podiatrist*, if we want our hearts checked, we go to a *cardiologist*. Why, then, if we have a hand problem, do we go to a hand surgeon or a hand doctor and not a *manologist*?

Comment: If there were a thing, it would be a "xeriatrist" or "cheriatry," not "manologist."  If "podiatry" is the medical specialty for the feet, then the medical specialty for the hands would be "xeriatry" or "cheriatry."  That's because the names are based on Greek, not Latin.  The word for "foot" in Greek is "podi."  The word for hand in Greek is "xeri."  The X, though, which is the letter chi, often gets transliterated as "ch" into languages that use the Latin alphabet, which in English gets pronounced like a K.

Comment: @sumelic But some people do go to a "manicurist" , or at least have their nails "manicured" don't they?

Comment: What I can't figure out is why they call foot pain a "face plant" (or whatever that Latinized/Greekified version of "face plant" is that they use).

Comment: @WS2:  Yes, and it seems that "chiriatry" has occasionally been used to refer to the art of manicuring.

Comment: @sumelic So where does "chiropody" come from? That's to do with feet isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Well, a word "chiriatry" with the meaning "medical treatment of the hand or hands" supposedly exists ([English Word Information](http://wordinfo.info/results/chiriatry)). But this word seems to be rare enough that it doesn't actually have a single, specific meaning that is widely recognized—that web page says it can also mean "Healing by the laying on of hands", and *[The Text Book of Chiropody](https://books.google.com/books?id=Tw41AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA49&lpg=PA49&dq=chiriatry&source=bl&ots=hOz5OlV9Fh&sig=gjWtuYEz64pConNehAk2nzgvAfc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiCmOeqtpjcAhWniVQKHQmkBZoQ6AEIOTAD#v=onepage&q=chiriatry&f=false)* (by Maurice J. Lewi, 1914) says "'chiriatry' is the only correct scientific expression for manicuring".

As Billy indicated in a comment, *podiatrist* and *cardiologist* are based on Greek, not Latin: the Latin roots for "foot" and "heart" are *ped-* and *cord-*. The Greek root for "hand" is *χειρ-*, but it's common to use Latinized forms in the composition of English words, so usually it shows up as *chir-* (as in the word *chiral*); occasionally variant transliterations like *cheir-* and *cher-* are used. The Modern Greek word *χέρι* is related, but modern Greek is traditionally not the source of English classical compounds.

The words *chirology* and *chirologist* also exist, but don't refer to medicine but rather palm-reading, apparently. "Cherology/cheirology" has been used in reference to sign languages.